# Bag of Words with json array

Tags: python, classification, document-classification

I'm trying to follow this tutorial in order to make a custom bag of words.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus = [
'All my cats in a row',
    'When my cat sits down, she looks like a Furby toy!',
    'The cat from outer space',
    'Sunshine loves to sit like this for some reason.'
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
print( vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense() )
print( vectorizer.vocabulary_ )
```

This script print that:

```
[[1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]]
{u'all': 0, u'sunshine': 20, u'some': 18, u'down': 3, u'reason': 13, u'looks': 9, u'in': 7, u'outer': 12, u'sits': 17, u'row': 14, u'toy': 24, u'from': 5, u'like': 8, u'for': 4, u'space': 19, u'this': 22, u'sit': 16, u'when': 25, u'cat': 1, u'to': 23, u'cats': 2, u'she': 15, u'loves': 10, u'furby': 6, u'the': 21, u'my': 11}
```

So here's my problem: I have a json file with this data structure:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "class": "positive",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "class": "negative",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag3"
        ]
    }
]
```

So I'm trying to vectorize the tags array without any success.

I've tried something like this:

```
data = json.load(open('data.json'));
print( vectorizer.fit_transform(data).todense() )
```

also:

```
for element in data:
print( vectorizer.fit_transform(element).todense() ) 
#or 
print( vectorizer.fit_transform(element['tags']).todense() )
```

nobody works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Use pandas to read the json file into a `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_json('data.json', orient='values')
print(df)
```

This is what your `DataFrame` should look like:

```
Out[]:       
      class  id          tags
0  positive   1  [tag1, tag2]
1  negative   2  [tag1, tag3]
```

### 2. Convert the tags column from `list` to `str`

```
df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
print(df)
```

This will result in converting `tags` to space separated strings:

```
Out[]:       
class  id       tags
0  positive   1  tag1 tag2
1  negative   2  tag1 tag3
```

### 3. Plug the `tags` column / pandas `Series` into `CountVectorizer`

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
print(vectorizer.fit_transform(df['tags']).todense())
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

This will result in the output that you want:

```
Out[]:       
[[1 1 0]
 [1 0 1]]
{'tag1': 0, 'tag2': 1, 'tag3': 2}
```

Comment: I could not ask for a better and more detailed answer. Thank you very very much.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Comment: Other little question. If I want to include the class as first  position of the vector? To be more specific, in my example the class is only two (positive and negative), but in fact I've more than two class. Thankyou again